# In Azure function that returns ServiceBus message, how do I conditionally returning message?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have an azure function which returns a service bus message. However, I want to conditionally return a service bus message, instead of being forced to return the message every time.

here is an example

```
[FunctionName("ServiceBusOutput")]
[return: ServiceBus("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
public static string ServiceBusOutput([HttpTrigger] dynamic input, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# function processed: {input.Text}");

    // check condition here, abort return completely

    // Otherwise, return

    return input.Text;
}
```

Said another way, I want to return a message on a service bus when certain conditions apply within the function code block. Is this possible?

One idea that does not work is to throw an exception. However, this just results in the message being placed into the DL queue. I want to completely abort the operation of returning the message on the service bus, and avoid DL.

Another idea that does not work is to simply execute

```
return;
```

But this results in compile-time error, which is sort of expected
"An object of a type convertible to 'MyReturnType1' is required"

I can think of a hack which I dont like, which is to return null, and handle the null later in the chain. But this is sort of dirty to me.

Comment: Return one of the message in the queue or return the whole queue message?

Comment: @BowmanZhu, can you please clarify your question more?

Comment: In your code, I notice the `myqueue`, but you say that you want to return a message. Actually, the trigger will return all of the message.

Comment: the function above adds a message onto the queue/topic named myqueue after the function block completes execution successfully

Comment: @joey, could you send message with my code?

Comment: My question specifically is how to accomplish the task using the service bus bindings. I belive your answer is : dont use binding. I'm aware that this may solve the higher level problem, but specifically I am looking to see if I can keep the binding if possible. Does that make sense?

Comment: Why do you think my code doesn't use binding, check the [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/pull/1753), it's the service bus binding, it's just not your sample return binding.

Answer (score 1):

Just return null from the function and it will not send message.

Answer (score 0):

You could just bind `ServiceBus` as `MessageSender` type, then use the `SendAsync()` method to send the message.

The below is my test code, if the request name equals "george", it will send the name to the message queue.

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [ServiceBus("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] MessageSender messagesQueue,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;
            if (name.Equals("george")) {
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name);
                Message m1 = new Message();
                m1.Body = bytes;
                await messagesQueue.SendAsync(m1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Suppose this is what you want, hope this could help you, if you still have other problem please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the output binding available in Azure Function, you can send a message to the queue from a custom queue client created inside the function.

Posting the message based on a condition is not possible with the bindings.

Comment: Got it. Yes, this is what I mentioned in my comments above. removing output binding and instead using a service client in the function block. Thanks.